# OutOfMemoryException while trying to read big Excel file into DataTable

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, etl, script-task

I'm using SSIS package to clean and load data from .Xlsx file to SQL Server table. 
I have also to highlight cells containing wrong data in .Xlsx file, for this I have to get back column and row indexes based on column name and row id(witch I have in my data spreadsheet). For that I compare each column name from my first spreadsheet (`Error_Sheet`) with rows of a column that I added in a second spreadsheet and do the same for rows, and if I have the same value of cells I get back the column and row indexes of my data spreadsheet and highlight the cell based on that column and row index. The script worked fine, but after trying to run it from a server I got an Memory exception and also on my workstation where it was working fine before.

I've tried to reduce the range that I'm taking data from : `AC1:AC10000` to `AC1:AC100`, it worked only after the first time compilation, but it keeps throwing exception again.

```
string strSQLErrorColumns = "Select * From [" + Error_Sheet + "AC1:AC100]";
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(strCn);

OleDbDataAdapter objAdapterErrorColumns = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQLErrorColumns, cn);
System.Data.DataSet dsErrorColumns = new DataSet();
objAdapterErrorColumns.Fill(dsErrorColumns, Error_Sheet);
System.Data.DataTable dtErrorColumns = dsErrorColumns.Tables[Error_Sheet];
dsErrorColumns.Dispose();
objAdapterErrorColumns.Dispose();

foreach (DataColumn ColumnData in dtDataColumns.Columns){
    ColumnDataCellsValue = dtDataColumns.Columns[iCntD].ColumnName.ToString();
    iCntE = 0;

    foreach (DataRow ColumnError in dtErrorColumns.Rows){
        ColumnErrorCellsValue = dtErrorColumns.Rows[iCntE].ItemArray[0].ToString();

        if (ColumnDataCellsValue.Equals(ColumnErrorCellsValue)){

            ColumnIndex = ColumnData.Table.Columns[ColumnDataCellsValue].Ordinal;
            iCntE = iCntE + 1;
            break;
            }
        }

        iCntD = iCntD + 1;
    }

ColumnIndexHCell = ColumnIndex + 1;          
RowIndexHCell = RowIndex + 2;

Range rng = xlSheets.Cells[RowIndexHCell, ColumnIndexHCell] as Excel.Range;
rng.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
```

There is any other way to load data in DataTable to get column and row index without using a lot of memory or by using `Excel.Range.Cell` instead of dataset and DataTable to get Cell value, column  and row index from xlsx file please ?

I didn't show the whole code because it's long. Please keep me informed if more information needed.

Comment: I'm confused, why is this tagged as SSIS if you are not using SSIS to read in the data? An SSIS Excel connection manager will handle the caching and buffering of rows, so no C# is required.

Comment: @M.ECH is the issue solved??

Comment: @JWeezy, as montioned, I'm using SSIS to clean and load data from .Xlsx file to SQL Server table and then I use a script task to highlight cells containing unmatched data.

Comment: @Yahfoufi, yes but I didn't use `Paging` as proposed by @Hadi because I don't have enough time to aplly it so I used `Excel.Range` to handle it. Thanks for caring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to read data from an Excel with huge number of Rows, it is better to read data by chunk *(in OleDbDataAdapter you can use paging option to achieve that)*.

```
int result = 1;
int intPagingIndex = 0;
int intPagingInterval = 1000;

while (result > 0){

    result = daGetDataFromSheet.Fill(dsErrorColumns,intPagingIndex, intPagingInterval , Error_Sheet);
    System.Data.DataTable dtErrorColumns = dsErrorColumns.Tables[Error_Sheet];

    //Implement your logic here

    intPagingIndex += intPagingInterval ;

}
```

This will prevent an OutOfMemory Exception. And no more need to specify a range like `AC1:AC10000`

**References**

- [Paging Through a Query Result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/paging-through-a-query-result)
- [Fill(DataSet, Int32, Int32, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_Common_DbDataAdapter_Fill_System_Data_DataSet_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_String_)

Comment: sorry I couldn't answer before today. I actually used the `Interop` instead of `Paging` It took me less time to apply it. But I will use it and especially understand it once I have more availability next time. 
Thanks again for your precious help as usual.